# Closed form for mass function of maximum of discrete uniform RV's

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose you roll $n$ fair $k$-sided dice, denoting these rolls $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ and define $Y = \mathrm{max}(X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_n)$. I have read several results which state that the distribution function of $Y$ is

$$F_Y(y) = (F_{X_i}(y))^n$$
since the $X_i$ are iid.

Then, this should be $$F_Y(y) = \left(\frac{\lfloor y \rfloor}{k}\right)^n.$$

Is there a way to recover the probability mass function from this, in general? I know for a given $n$ and $k$ I could work out all of the probabilities and subtract to get the individual masses, but that does not seem ideal.

Comment: The expression for $F_Y(y)$ should not involve $x$.  It is a function of $y$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp you're correct, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$\mathbb P(Y \le y)= F_Y(y) = \left(\dfrac{y}{k}\right)^n$$ for $y \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,k\}$ (no rounding is needed as $y$ is an integer), then $$\mathbb P(Y = y)= F_Y(y)-F_Y(y-1)=\left(\dfrac{y}{k}\right)^n-\left(\dfrac{y-1}{k}\right)^n =\dfrac{y^n-(y-1)^m}{k^n}$$ for $y \in \{1,2,\ldots,k\}$.  This is a closed from.

Comment: Thanks, I even mentioned subtraction in my post and didn't think about this...floor function is included in the CDF since the CDF should be defined on R but I understand why the floor isn't needed in the mass function.